# How do i remove values after comma in json

Tags: python

I am trying to parse below json and add values into csv file but i am having problem on how to remove values after comma. Below is my json -

```
 {
                  "code" : "12345",
                  "system" : "SYS1",
                  "value" : "AB345,AC1234,BC123"
     }
```

this is output that i am getting in csv file -

```
  value
 "AB345,AC1234,BC123"
```

but i am expecting instead -

```
value
"AB345"
```

wondering how do i remove the values after comma ?

Comment: It seems possible you would want to preserve that data, and create one row for each of the comma separated values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split method with delimiter "," and get zeroth index of the array.

> s = "AB345,AC1234,BC123".split(",", 1)[0]

Comment: when you only need the first value, it's a good practice to limit number of splits: `.split(",", 1)`